# how to change web server folder location in xampp

Tags: xampp

I have installed xampp and by default my website files are stored in htdocs. How do I change the webdirectory path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit the file /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf and change the lines containing current web directory path. It should start with DocumentRoot. Update all the places having the current path to the path you would like it to be.

Answer (score 6):

It can be done by editing the "httpd.conf" file present in this path "\xampp\apache\conf\".

Change the line that starts with "Directory ...".

Note that all the lines that start with a hash (#) are just comments and are there just to describe the commands present there in the file.

Answer (score 0):

search for the file "httpd.conf" and change the path in that file.

Comment: You need to be more explicit in what you mean by "change the path"

Answer (score 0):

[change localhost's name ?](http://w3-video.com/Web_Tools/XAMPP/xampp_access_change_localhost.html)  thus instead of having localhostdomain/webdirectory

you may have newdomain/webdirectory ?